# How to show a random selection of posts from the search

Tags: search

I want to show only a random selected number of search results from a search. Its different to the random output from a category. Any Ideas how to do this? it is for a big database to give every post of the search result the chance to be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do using the `pre_get_posts` action hook to set the `orderby`  to `rand` in the query, something like this:

```
function random_search_result( $q ) {
    if ( is_search() && is_main_query() )
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand');
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'random_search_result' );
```